# Debugging Intellij Idea Plugin in Android Studio on Windows

Tags: android-studio, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I am building an plugin for Intellij Idea / Android Studio and I am unable to debug it on Android Studio.

As i've seen in the documentation that in order to debug it in Android studio the ***alternativeIdePath*** needs to be set with the path to Android Studio. I did that but it seems that the path is not corect.

I did some research and I found how it sould be on mac and linux but not on Windows.

the values I tried are :

```
alternativeIdePath 'C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\bin\\studio64.exe'
```

and

```
alternativeIdePath 'C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\bin'
```

the error I got  for the first variant is  : 
 ***Directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe' specified for property 'ideaDirectory' is not a directory.***

and for the second is:
***C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\build.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)***

Do you know how it should be set for windows?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition? Till the recent time they only supported debugging in a community version. I do not see this in the documentation anymore, though, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota I am able to debug it in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition but the plugin I am trying to make is intended for android development and it will make my life a lot easier if I would be able de debug it in Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

You should change alternativeIdePath to:

```
alternativeIdePath 'C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio'
```